# webpack + babel, transpiling dependencies

Tags: vue.js, webpack, babeljs, es6-modules, aws-appsync

I'm creating an app made with vuejs. This app i using **AWS Appsync services** for communicating.

Unfortunately i need to support old browsers like ie 10/11 and the module developed by **amazon aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-js** and other sub dependencies are build using es6.

So, i have tried to transpile dependencies using webpack and babel but when i run app in any browser (ff, chrome too) i got this **error**: `exports is not defined`.
Is refereed to a row of a dependency how i have tried to transpile

```
node_modules/aws-appsync/node_modules/debug/src/browser

exports.log = log;
```

Any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should be `module.exports.log = log` instead. At least according to [this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/).

Or if you want to use ES6 native exports: `export {log}`.